# heatmap with ggplot2: what is it next to the legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I drew a heatmap using **ggplot2**. It's all fine expect, there is something "unknown" appearing next to the legend, that is `5` `a` `5` (see the pic below).

Can anyone explain what it is, please? And, how can I get rid off it?

Why `5`? why `a`? (I have 5 NAs in my heatmap??)

Here is the code:

```
hm <- ggplot(data=molten, aes(x=factor(Var2, levels=month.abb), y=Var1, fill=value)) + geom_tile()
hm <- hm + scale_fill_gradient2(low=LtoM(100), mid=Mid, high=MtoH(100))
hm <- hm + labs(fill='Return (%)')
hm <- hm + geom_text(aes(label=paste(sprintf("%.1f %%", value)), size=5))
```

[image: hm]

Comment: If remember all the syntax correctly, you tried to set something inside a call to `aes` when it should be mapped. Post your code.

Comment: Put size=5 outside the aes() in geom_text(). If it is inside the aes() then legend is made.

Comment: it seems you were right. it is tied to `size=5` in `geom_text(aes(label=paste(sprintf("%.1f %%", value)), size=5))` .  i wished to set the size of the numbers inside the heatmap to 5

Comment: thank you Didzis. You are right. I had to put size=5 outside of the aes() scope.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was given by `Didzis Elferts` in the comments: It suffice to put `size=5` outside of `aes()`

replace:

```
hm <- hm + geom_text(aes(label=paste(sprintf("%.1f %%", value))), size=5)
```

by:

```
hm <- hm + geom_text(aes(label=paste(sprintf("%.1f %%", value)), size=5))
```